# Getting the decriptions of the tables and columns via a sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database and a lot of tables inside it. I wrote some information into the each table and column's decription part. And now using query i want to see all table and columns descriptions.

Note: DATABASE -> ms sql server

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName 
  , td.value AS TableDescription
  , c.name AS ColumnName
  , cd.value AS ColumnDescription
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties td 
    ON td.major_id = t.object_id
    AND td.minor_id = 0
    AND td.name = 'MS_Description'
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties cd 
    ON cd.major_id = t.object_id
    AND cd.minor_id = c.column_id
    AND cd.name = 'MS_Description'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see that using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

To get columns for each table you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

To get table information you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user_col_comments;
```

This will display all tables's column with comments for the logged in user.

```
select * from user_col_comments where table_name = '<table name>';
```

This will display specified tables's column with comments for the logged in user.

Comment: provided if user comment is added for the tables , and i doubt weather it works in mysql or not , oracle yes .

Answer (score 0):

```
desc table_name query is used to describe the table
```